# Linking CSS file to my HTML file doesn't work whatever I do

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to link to a CSS file in my HTML index file. It's just one line of code and apparently whatever I try it doesn't work. I'm using VSCode.

- If I type the link from beginning it also auto-completes (or it shows it anyway). So it knows it's there.
- I've also tried moving the CSS file out of the folder and next to the HTML file. But that doesn't work either.
- I tried the style brackets in the HTML file itsself and the coloring there works.

So my way of testing is that nothing is showing up blue.

I also removed my Javascript from the HTML file into a seperate file linking to it for readability for this question, and that *does* work

Does anybody else have any idea's?

I also saw the other topics for this same question but it shows nothing new to try out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel=”stylesheet” type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <a id="stringCalculation"></a><br>
    <a id="stringResult"></a>
    <br>
    <div id="container-numbers">
    <button id="one" class="number">1</button>
    <button id="two" class="number">2</button>
    <button id="three" class="number">3</button>
    <button id="four" class="number">4</button>
    <button id="five" class="number">5</button>
    <button id="six" class="number">6</button>
    <button id="seven" class="number">7</button>
    <button id="eight" class="number">8</button>
    <button id="nine" class="number">9</button>
    <button id="zero" class="number">0</button>
    </div>
    <div id="operators">
    <button id="symbolPlus" class="operator">+</button>
    <button id="symbolMinus" class="operator">-</button>
    <button id="symbolTimes" class="operator">*</button>
    <button id="symbolDivid" class="operator">/</button>
    <button id="equals">=</button>
    </div>
    <div id="other">
    <button id="clearButton">Clear</button><br>
    <button id="backspace">Backsp</button>
    <button id="decimal">.</button>
    </div>

    <script src="javascript/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS file:

```
#one {
    background-color: blue;
}
.number {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here my folder:

[image: folder structure]

And inside:

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Can show your folder structure? This working properly.

Comment: Check DevTools Network tab. Does file is loaded? Check Inspector tab, does elements has applied CSS that is overwritten?

Comment: I really suppose theres a problem with the path of the CSS file you are linking to your HTML. Maybe you have a link where it can be checked?

Comment: it should be visible now

Comment: This is a typo `”stylesheet”` - change the quotes to standard quotes.

Comment: Right, that's it. It was the quotes. They were off apparently, I can see it now. Thanks. Changing the quotes worked. And I chose the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
   <link rel=”stylesheet” type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
```

With

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please user opening and closing double inverted commas.
Please try this line of code:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
```